# How to add a custom column with csv.writer

Tags: python, csv

I have a python script that takes a huge file and copies out only the few columns that I want while also writing a new custom header in the new file.

```
import csv,time,string,os, requests

og_file = "\\\\network\\x\\test.csv"
today = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")


#fields to keep from original file
fields = ["As Of Date", "Ph", "Home Country"]

with open(og_file) as infile, open("c:\\upload\\output_" + today + ".csv", "wb") as outfile:
    r = csv.DictReader(infile)
    w = csv.DictWriter(outfile, fields, extrasaction="ignore")

    wtr = csv.writer( outfile )    
    wtr.writerow(["upload_date", "phone", "country"])
    for row in r:
        w.writerow(row)
```

As I write this file, I need to create an additional column at the beginning of each row with a number, starting at 1 and going to *n*, so the output looks like this:

```
id |    upload_date    |    phone    |   country
1        2012-01-01         555-1234      USA
2        2012-02-01         555-1235      USA
3        2012-03-01         555-1236      USA
4        2012-04-01         555-1237      USA
```

I'm not sure how I would go about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
fields = ["id"] + fields  # so it'll write later

with open(og_file) as infile, open("c:\\upload\\output_" + today + ".csv", "wb") as outfile:
    r = csv.DictReader(infile)
    w = csv.DictWriter(outfile, fields, extrasaction="ignore")

    wtr = csv.writer( outfile )    
    wtr.writerow(["id","upload_date", "phone", "country"])
    for i,row in enumerate(r, start=1):
        row["id"] = i
        w.writerow(row)
```

Comment: that makes perfect sense, I just wasn't sure of the syntax.  Thank you!

Comment: @BrianPowell not a problem

Comment: You can skip the off-by-one error correction of `i+1` by doing `for i, row in enumerate(r, start=1):`

Comment: @AdamSmith yes, it is better.

Comment: Note that this will not work (i.e. `[i+1] + row`) as `row` is a `dict` in this case and not a list

Comment: @MosesKoledoye is right - I get `TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "dict") to list`

Comment: @galaxyan I edited to correct the small error. Your mileage may vary.

Comment: @AdamSmith thank you Adam - this fixed the issue and it works perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `itertools.count` object for the `id` column:

```
from itertools import count

with open(og_file) as infile, open("c:\\upload\\output_" + today + ".csv", "wb") as outfile:
    r = csv.DictReader(infile)
    w = csv.DictWriter(outfile, fields, extrasaction="ignore")

    wtr = csv.writer( outfile )    
    wtr.writerow(["id", "upload_date", "phone", "country"])
    c = count(1)
    for row in r:
        row['id'] = next(c)
        w.writerow(row)
```

Comment: This is great too!  Spanning it over multiple lines is helpful in understanding exactly what's going on.  Thanks so much!

Comment: Hmmm.  The column header `id` is appearing, but I'm not getting a counted list in that first column. I'm getting the data for `upload_date` in the first column instead.

Comment: Did you include `id` to `fields = ["id", "As Of Date", "Ph", "Home Country"]`?

Comment: Ah - okay.  That fixed it.  Thanks!